# opendnp3 (master-gprs-tls-demo) and (outstation-tls-demo)

Tags: dnp3

When running master-gprs-tls-demo (on master Raspberrypi) or running outstation-tls-demo (on outstation Raspberrypi), i receive these messages:

On Outstation terminal:
usage: master-gprs-tls-demo

On Master-gprs terminal:
usage: master-gprs-tls-demo

Any help to work on it in clear steps would be highly appreciated.

Comment: usage: master-gprs-tls-demo <peer certificate> <local certificate chain> <private key>

Comment: usage: master-gprs-tls-demo <ca certificate> <certificate chain> <private key>